# Add iPad storyboard to existing iphone project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I created my project for just iphone/ipod users. Now i want to make it work for ipad users also. I have 2 storyboards; 3.5 inch and 4 inch.

Here is my steps:

1)I created a new storyboard. File - New File - User Interface - Storyboard for iPad.

2)I changed target devices from iphone to universal.

3)I set main storyboard in iPad deployment info section.

4)Finally i copied everything on storyboard for 4 inch iphone and paste it on new storyboard for ipad. (I did not change anything including screen sizes)

I tried to put just one view controller on new storyboard but the result was same.

Then i run and built my app on iPad simulator. And i get an error below:

```
2013-07-28 19:02:42.151 Test[40038:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController topViewController]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7888940'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b02012 0x1573e7e 0x1b8d4bd 0x1af1bbc 0x1af194e 0x252b 0x2626 0x4b5157 0x4b5747   
0x4b694b 0x4c7cb5 0x4c8beb 0x4ba698 0x194cdf9 0x194cad0 0x1a77bf5 0x1a77962 0x1aa8bb6 
0x1aa7f44 0x1aa7e1b 0x4b617a 0x4b7ffc 0x1d5d 0x1c85)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This is in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)initializeStoryBoardBasedOnScreenSize {

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{    // The iOS device = iPhone or iPod Touch


    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
    {   // iPhone 3GS, 4, and 4S and iPod Touch 3rd and 4th generation: 3.5 inch screen (diagonally measured)

        // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone35
        UIStoryboard *iPhone35Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard_iphone35" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone35Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

    if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 568)
    {   // iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5th generation: 4 inch screen (diagonally measured)

        // Instantiate a new storyboard object using the storyboard file named Storyboard_iPhone4
        UIStoryboard *iPhone4Storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

        // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
        UIViewController *initialViewController = [iPhone4Storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Instantiate a UIWindow object and initialize it with the screen size of the iOS device
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        // Set the initial view controller to be the root view controller of the window object
        self.window.rootViewController  = initialViewController;

        // Set the window object to be the key window and show it
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

} else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

{   // The iOS device = iPad

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;

}
}
```

Would anyone be able to explain whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last object in your split view controller is not UINavigationController. Check your storyboard.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
```

Comment: Thank you Timur. I totally forget that i changed the controllers.